NPM dependency errors with React 19
I had some dependency errors when running
npx create-react-app . --template typescript

This was fixed by running:
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
npm i

This fixes the installation problems. However, when I run
npm list react react-dom typescript

I get the following error:
@testing-library/react@13.4.0
│ ├── react-dom@19.0.0 deduped invalid: "^18.0.0" from node_modules/@testing-library/react
│ └── react@19.0.0 deduped invalid: "^18.0.0" from node_modules/@testing-library/react
├─┬ react-dom@19.0.0 invalid: "^18.0.0" from node_modules/@testing-library/react
│ └── react@19.0.0 deduped invalid: "^18.0.0" from node_modules/@testing-library/react
├─┬ react-scripts@5.0.1
│ ├─┬ eslint-config-react-app@7.0.1
│ │ └─┬ @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.62.0
│ │   └─┬ tsutils@3.21.0
│ │     └── typescript@4.9.5 deduped
│ │ └─┬ fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.3
│ ├── react@19.0.0 deduped invalid: "^18.0.0" from node_modules/@testing-library/react
│ └── typescript@4.9.5 deduped
├── react@19.0.0 invalid: "^18.0.0" from node_modules/@testing-library/react
└── typescript@4.9.5

npm error code ELSPROBLEMS
npm error invalid: react-dom@19.0.0 C:\...\frontend\node_modules\react-dom       
npm error invalid: react@19.0.0 C:\...\frontend\node_modules\react
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\...AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-20T01_08_05_151Z-debug-0.log

I tried reinstalling npm using
npm install --legacy-peer-deps 

To no avail. What can I do here?
